# How to show date between start date and end date in ms access

Tags: java, database, ms-access, prepared-statement

i have error in my code

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: 
     UCAExc:::3.0.7 unexpected token: 2016 required: AND
```

and this is my code

```
try{
    String sql = "Select id,nama,grup,tanggal from kuli where  tanggal between '"+ctgl.getText()+"' 'AND' '"+ctgl1.getText()+"'";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL should be like this:

```
String sql = "Select id, nama, grup, tanggal from kuli where tanggal between #" + ctgl.getText() + "# and #" + ctgl1.getText() + "#";
```

and `ctgl.getText()` and `ctgl1.getText()` must return strings formatted as: 2016/11/05

Comment: amazing !!!! thank you brooo ...... it work......thank you very much :D

Comment: OK, thanks, then please mark as answered. And don't forget the general and good advice to use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing proper `date` for `ctgl.getText()`, because which the `SQL` query is failed to retrieve the data. Also, do not use the 'AND' with quotes.

You need to ensure that you are passing the correct date format.

Also, it is NOT recommended to use the `prepareStatement` like this (i.e., in your code formed the sql using string concatenations) which will allow the cross site scripting, rather the best practice is to use `prepareStatement.setString()`, `setDate()`, etc.. methods,

You can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) about cross site scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. It looks like your SQL syntax is broken.  There should not be quotes around the `AND` keyword.
2. You should not be embedding the parameter values into the SQL like that.  Instead, you should be using a `PreparedStatement` and place-holder parameters.

Using `PreparedStatement` has a number of advantages:

- It means that you don't need figure out how to quote values.
- It means that you don't need figure out the correct syntax for date/time literals.
- It means that you don't need to worry about SQL injection attacks.

The last one is really important if the parameter values come from a source that you cannot completely trust.

More information:

- [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)